# TextViews inside a loop

Tags: android

I want to display String Array values inside a for loop. I need to display the each value to each TextView. How can I create TextView dynamically corresponding to the size of Array? How can I specify ID for each one ? Please give me the solution... Thank You..

Comment: why do you want to do that? did you mean about ListView?

Comment: I want to display String Array values inside a for loop. I need to display the each value to each TextView. How can I create TextView dynamically corresponding to the size of Array? How can I specify ID for each one ?
Please give me the solution...
Thank You..

Comment: Please edit your questions instead of posting duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

As written in the comments, you should use a ListView : It's dedicated to such a purpose.

It's definitely a bad idea because instantiating TextViews in a loop is not an optimized behavior. If you have many items in your array, it will take a lot of CPU resources and it will fill up the memory.

Take a look to the ListView object : it's easier to implement and optimized for the system.
Check this for more info : http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html